# Error when sending mail with Laravel and PHP 8.1

Tags: laravel

My server (Ubuntu 20.4) updated and this impacted the version of PHP which was upgraded to 8.1 and since I got this error message when I try to send a mail from my Laravel application:

> strtolower(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($string) of type string is deprecated

My current PHP version is 8.1 and Laravel 8.64.0.

Need help!

I looked in this forum (https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/39686), but the I'm a little bit confused because I don't see any entry in my composer.json file and yet Swiftmailer is already part of the project.

[image: Error message]

Comment: Refer this https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/39686

Comment: Hi @JohnLobo. How do I update the version of Swiftmailer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also faced the same problem I just upgraded my swiftmailer by this command

```
composer require "swiftmailer/swiftmailer:^6.3"
```

Answer (score 4):

> Please upgrade to Swiftmailer 6.3.0 which provides PHP 8.1 support.

Comment: Hi @vivek. How to proceed ? I don't see any entry in my composer.json file and yet Swiftmailer is already part of the project.

Comment: composer require swiftmailer/swiftmailer

Answer (score 0):

If swiftmailer is not in your composer.json, then how is it a part of your project? Kindly verify.
For getting the latest stable version you can simply use the command

```
composer require swiftmailer/swiftmailer
```

Just FYI, this package is abandoned now and no more maintained. Instead you should use `symfony/mailer`.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: reason may be due to swiftmailer is used inside another package as is installed as dependency. looking at composer.lock file tells you where it is used as dependency.